# Signs of the lasso solution

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

Let us consider the following lasso estimator:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{L} = \arg\min \, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n}||y_{i} - \textbf{x}_{i}\beta||_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda_{n}}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{p}|\beta_{j}|
$$
Assume, that $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $rank(\mathbf{X}) = p$.

Then, the MLE solution $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$ is unique and assume that it is  such that all the components of the vector $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$ are non-negative.

Does the same hold for LASSO solution (the sign will be the same or they are zero)?

EDIT: It seems that for general $\textbf{X}$ it is possible.

Would it still be true for orthogonal design?

Would it be true in the case when $p=n$ and $\textbf{X} = \textbf{I}$?

PS. It seems so from the geometry of the problem in 2d and 3d cases. Though I can not to show it for a general dimension.

Comment: Your question is tantamount to asking whether the curves in a Lasso trace plot can cross zero.  In that regard I find the examples at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206178 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220801 (here on CV) and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_lars.html to be interesting (although I'm not convinced any of these are a true Lasso). It would be nice to understand this phenomenon better (+1).

Comment: Dear @whuber, I see that it is possible for a general design $X$. I have modified the question. Is the statement true for the case when $n=p$ and $X = I$?

Comment: I have found simple examples of this sign-switching phenomenon even in $3$ dimensions.  They tend to involve sizable negative correlations among some of the variables.

Comment: even for orthogonal design?

Comment: "Negative correlations" means, *a fortiori,* not orthogonal! Note that orthogonality isn't quite as meaningful or useful a concept for the Lasso as in other contexts, because the $L^1$ penalty distinguishes the coordinates.

Comment: Dear @whuber, ok, may be it is not, but I would just like to understand it for myself if it the statement could be true in some (may be not very real) cases.

Comment: When the design matrix is orthogonal, varying one parameter estimate in OLS does not affect the other parameter estimates. Thus, if you suppose there is a case where the Lasso solution involves a negative parameter estimate, simply switch its sign and observe (1) the penalty remains the same; (2) all other OLS estimates remain the same; but (3) because the original OLS solution had a positive coefficient, the OLS term *decreases.* This shows the supposed solution did not minimize the objective. Thus a negative Lasso parameter estimate is impossible in this circumstance.

Comment: Dear @whuber, I see, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here.  Let's look at the general one first: **Is it possible for the Lasso to reverse the signs of estimated coefficients?**

The answer is yes.  It can occur when two variables are strongly negatively correlated with one another but positively correlated with a third.  Here is an example of such a design matrix $X:$

$$X = \pmatrix{0.4 & 0.6 & -0.8 \\ -1.0 & 0.9 & -0.9 \\ 1.0 & -1.0 & 0.9 \\ -0.6 & -0.1 & 0.9}$$

Taking the response to be

$$y = (0.1, -1.0, 1.0, 0.3)^\prime$$

the OLS estimates for the model (with intercept, which is going to be part of the Lasso) are approximately

$$\hat\beta = (0.04, 0.89, 0.80, 0.97)^\prime,$$

all of which are positive.

Using the `glmnet` package for `R` in its default (Lasso) mode produces sequences of estimates for a large range of possible $\lambda.$  The *Lasso trace* plots these sequences as line graphs.  Given a design matrix `x` and response vector `y`, here is the code to produce the Lasso trace:

```R
fit <- glmnet(x,y)
plot(fit)
```

The horizontal axis reflects the size of the penalty ("L1 Norm") while the vertical axis represents the estimated coefficients $\hat\beta(\lambda).$  This plot is best read right to left: at the right the penalty is large because $\lambda$ is small (but nonzero, so the coefficients aren't quite the same as the OLS estimates).  Scanning to the left, the values of $\lambda$ increase, putting more weight on the penalty and pushing the estimates to zero.

Typically, once an estimate hits zero it stays there.  But this one is different:

[image: Lasso trace]

The estimated coefficients of the columns of $X$ are (from left to right in the matrix) shown in gold, light blue, and gray. The light blue estimate initially hits zero (where the $L^1$ Norm is between $0.8$ and $1.1$), but then the gray estimate  drops *while the light blue estimate becomes negative.*

In effect, *the Lasso is trading the second and third variables off for one another.*  This can be anticipated by examining the correlation matrix of $X:$

$$\operatorname{Cor}(X) = \pmatrix{1 & -0.68 & 0.34 \\ -0.68 & 1 & -0.89 \\ 0.34 & -0.89 & 1},$$

showing how strongly *anticorrelated* the last two variables are.

---

The second question asks **whether the same phenomenon can occur when $X$ is orthogonal.**  The answer is no.

In this case, varying one parameter estimate in OLS does not affect the other parameter estimates. Thus, if you suppose there is a case where the Lasso solution involves a negative parameter estimate, simply switch its sign and observe (1) the penalty remains the same; (2) all other OLS estimates remain the same; but (3) because the original OLS solution had a positive coefficient, the OLS term decreases. This shows the supposed solution did not minimize the objective. *Thus a negative Lasso parameter estimate is impossible in this circumstance.*

This analysis supports the claim in the first part of the question that the sign reversal must be due to the correlation patterns among the explanatory variables.